# I can print out each element of a an array by iterating through all values, but can't get 1 element [PHP]?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am using PHP and MongoDB. I can iterate through the array and print every value to the screen but when I just want to print 1 value, nothing comes out, and I don't get an error as well.

```
    <?php  

    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager(
    'mongodb+srv://removedUsername:removedPassword@cluster0-vqdka.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true');

    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([], [
    'MenusAttached' => true,
    ]);

    $rows = $mng->executeQuery('restaurantApp.restaurants', $query);
    $emptyArray = [];

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
    //echo $row->MenusAttached;
    array_push($emptyArray, $row->MenusAttached);
    }

    echo "Starting";
    //RELEVANT CODE BELOW.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($emptyArray); $i++) {
    echo $emptyArray[$i]; //THIS WORKS
    echo $emptyArray[1]; //BLANK, NOTHING COMES UP, NO ERROR. WHY?
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: what's the size of array? `echo count($emptyArray)` and share the output

Comment: `print_r($emptyArray)` and share the output

Comment: Try `$emptyArray[0]`

Comment: You should learn how to debug such errors, for example, `var_dump($emptyArray);` and see what is inside this array

Comment: Better to use `foreach()` when looping arrays. But, perhaps `$emptyArray[1];` is empty or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Instead of

```
array_push($emptyArray, $row->MenusAttached);
```

Use

```
$emptyArray[] = $row->MenusAttached;
```

2.Instead of `for()` loop use `foreach()` like below

```
foreach ( $emptyArray as $arr ){
    print_r($arr); // check the value and then proceed accordingly
}
```